# How to use iPhone internet tethering via USB with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, usb, iphone, connection-sharing

What are the steps to use iPhone 3G Internet tethering via USB on Ubuntu 10.04?

What software do I need to install on Ubuntu for this?  The phone is detected and I am able to play its songs in Ubuntu, also the tethering works fine on Windows OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had written a [post long ago on this](http://techie-buzz.com/foss/getting-iphone-internet-tethering-working-in-linux.html), writing it here as well.

Get the source from [Diego’s git repository](http://giagio.com/wiki/moin.cgi/iPhoneEthernetDriver). If you don’t have git installed, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

Once git is installed, get the source for the drivers

```
git clone git://github.com/dgiagio/ipheth.git
```

The output should be something like

```
sathya@shaman:~$ git clone git://github.com/dgiagio/ipheth.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/shaman/ipheth/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (10/10), 8.11 KiB, done.
sathya@shaman:~$
```

Now, compile the pairing program.

```
cd ipheth/ipheth-pair

make
```

You should get an output like:

```
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-pair$ make
gcc -Wall -O2 ipheth-pair.c -o ipheth-pair -liphone
```

Next, type:

```
sudo make install
```

You should get an output like:

```
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-pair$ sudo make install
install -m 0755 ipheth-pair /lib/udev/
install -m 0644 90-iphone-tether.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
/sbin/udevadm control –reload-rules
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-pair$
```

Compile the Kernel driver:

```
cd ipheth/ipheth-driver

make
```

You should get an output like:

```
sathya@shaman:~$ cd ipheth/ipheth-driver
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-driver$ make
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.28-15-generic/build M=/home/sathya/ipheth/ipheth-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15-generic’
CC [M] /home/sathya/ipheth/ipheth-driver/ipheth.o
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 1 modules
CC /home/sathya/ipheth/ipheth-driver/ipheth.mod.o
LD [M] /home/sathya/ipheth/ipheth-driver/ipheth.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.28-15-generic’
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-driver$
```

The kernel module is ready. Now load the module.

```
sudo insmod ipheth.ko
```

Now connect the iPhone. The iPhone should get detected, as shown in the picture.

[image]

To confirm that the USB Ethernet driver is in use, open the terminal and type

```
dmesg | grep iPhone
```

You should get an output like:

```
sathya@shaman:~/ipheth/ipheth-driver$ dmesg | grep iPhone
[22871.808469] ipheth 2-2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached
```

Switch on tethering.

[image]

To confirm that we have indeed connected using iPhone let’s have a look at Network Manager connections:

[image]

Comment: You should make this into a small blog post for the SU Blog, Sathya. +1 for awesomeness! :)

Comment: I would like to add that I needed to install "libimobiledevice-dev" package in order to be able to make ipheth-pair.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was run `sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils`. Nothing else worked, haha, seriously though.